# Configure JQ Validate to accept URL without http:// prefix

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery Validate and I need a custom validate method.

The default URL method will not accept a URL unless it has a schema.  My users will only ever be providing URL's that begin with http://, so I'd rather not have to put them through the hassle of typing it each time.

I am trying to create a validate method that will use the default URL method to check the validity of a URL.  If it fails, I want to prepend http:// and run it again.  Here's what I have so far:

```
addCustomUrlValidator: function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("short-url", function(value, element) {

        if (value.length == 0) return true;  // the field is optional

        // attempt to validate with default URL method.  Return true on valid.
        // ...

        // prepend http:// to value and attempt validation again.  Return true on valid.
        // ...

        return false

    }, jQuery.validator.format("Must be a valid URL format"));
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the field value with `.addMethod()`.  You can only output a true/false to indicate pass/fail of this custom rule.

Comment: To create this new method, look at the `url` method from [the plugin source](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js), copy its regex into your `.addMethod()` function and tweak it to ignore the protocol... in this case simply delete the `(https?|s?ftp):\/\/` part of the regex.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, if you write that up as the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Jquery Validate and I need a custom validate method.

See [the `.addMethod()` method documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) for how we do it below.

> The default URL method will not accept a URL unless it has a schema. My users will only ever be providing URL's that begin with `http://`, so I'd rather not have to put them through the hassle of typing it each time.

I've copied the function itself from the default `url` method [inside the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js) and edited the regex so that you don't need the URI scheme.  *(I simply deleted the `(https?|s?ftp):\/\/` part of the regex.)*  Notice this new rule is called `my_url`, and you can change that into whatever you want.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('my_url', function( value, element ) {
    // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/iri/
    return this.optional( element ) || /^(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test( value );
}, 'Please enter a valid url without the "http".');
```

> If it fails, I want to prepend `http://` and run it again.

Manipulating the data is something you should do on the server-side after the form has been submitted.  You should only return `true` or `false` from the custom method, not manipulate any data, nor programmatically force the same data through the same rule multiple times.  Either the user entered the correct format or he didn't... user then tries again.